# Using java System.currentTimeMillis() with a php script and mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a webapp (using php), my clients are java-based and are submitting dates to me using:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

so my web app gets it via a post, so it's a string, like:

```
$submittedTime = "9734367890508";
```

I want to insert it into a mysql table field, I think either a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP field can store it.

What type of field should I use, and how do I get that submitted value into the mysql table such that I can do queries later on using all the mysql time functions?

Thanks

Comment: I don't recommend having application code submit timestamps, use MySQL's date functions to get them.  If you have to compare timestamps per record, you can guarantee there won't be collisions.  And it's less headache to make sure formats match...

Comment: I don't have a choice here, it's just a feature of the client application where the user can perform some action locally, and the action is recorded with a timestamp using java's System.currentTimeMillis(). Later on, the clients will upload these timestamps to my php app. This is where I want to insert them into my database, but in mysqls DATETIME field type so that I can create reports and all that fun stuff from the inserted values.

Comment: By the way, is the timestamp you've used random or a real timestamp?  It appears to be for 2000-11-05 15:06:29... if I got that right.

Comment: Oh it's random, just an example.

Comment: Note: My last comment is wrong (I copied one too few digits).  Also, that timestamp example is actually beyond the range of a 32-bit signed UNIX timestamp, and would actually be for 2278-06-21 03:04:50.  It will overflow a standard UNIX timestamp formatter, though, and display 2001-12-13 14:45:52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use it with PHP, you'll have to divide it by 1000 to turn it into seconds.  Once it's in seconds, you can format it with the `date()` command, like so:

```
<?php
    // Get timestamp from somewhere and assume it's $timestamp
    $timestamp = (int) ($timestamp / 1000);
    // MySQL takes year-month-day hour:minute:second format
    $mysql_datetime = date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', $timestamp);
?>
```

Having said that, what's wrong with just using the time from PHP or MySQL themselves?  It's be the same date call in PHP, but without the second argument; or just setting the value to `NOW()` in MySQL.

Comment: Oh the clients are submitting timestamps to me from java, so there's no chance to use any of the php time functions. In your example, the variable $timestamp will initially be a String value of the submitted timestamp. So does dividing by an integer automatically parse it from a string to an integer in php? Furthermore, will the automatic conversion be able to hold the size of the value (because it will be a long, not an int really). Thanks!

Comment: PHP should auto-convert the timestamp to a float (on 32-bit platforms; it'd be cast to an int on 64-bit platforms), which after it's divided by 1000, should fall into the int range prior to the cast to an int.